# Underscore, retrieving value incorrectly

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am trying to retrieve a nested items value with a chain like so. The object I am traversing looks like this:

```js
var testStates = [{
        "module": "module1",
        "customUrl": [
            { "mod1": "2" },
            { "mod2": "1" }
        ]
    }, {
        "module": "module2",
        "customUrl": [
            { "mod3": "false" },
            { "mod4": "5" }
        ]
    }
];
```

And my chain looks like this:

```js
findState = _.chain(currentState)
              .findWhere({ module: moduleName})
              .result('customUrl')
              .find(function (v) { return v.hasOwnProperty(stateName)})
              .values()
              .value();
```

This is returning the right item however it is in an array by itself so if I `console.log` it, it gives me back `["false"]` instead of `"false"`. Not sure what is causing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
.result(stateName)
```

instead of

```
.values()
```

The former returns the value of an object by key, the latter - array of all values of the object.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/65j2r50t/